# Can anyone explain me this output?

Tags: c, printf, scanf, return-value

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    char arr[100];
    printf("%d", scanf("%s", arr));
    return 0;
}
```

Input value give for scanf is love2code

Comment: There is no output here!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And please [edit] your question to show us the expected and actual output. And tell us why the output you get is unexpected.

Comment: The output should be `1`. What do you get? Why do you think it should be otherwise? What do you think the return value of `scanf` will be?

Comment: This is the number of variables correctly assigned by scanf. Normally here 1

Answer (score 1):

According to the C Standard (7.21.6.4 The scanf function)

> 3 The scanf function returns the value of the macro EOF if an input
> failure occurs before the first conversion (if any) has completed.
> Otherwise, **the scanf function returns the number of input items
> assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero, in the
> event of an early matching failure.**

So if the call of scanf was successful

```
scanf("%s", arr)
```

then its returned value is equal to 1 that is outputted by the call of printf.

```
printf("%d", scanf("%s", arr));
```

This statement can be rewritten like

```
int result = scanf("%s", arr);
printf("%d", result);
```

Pay attention to that the output does not depend on what string was entered (provided that ii can be accommodate in the array arr, otherwise there will be undefined behavior). It is important that only one item (arr) was assigned.